# compilation error with pic model

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've got compilation error for the model "squaroid". I checked my code several times, but i'm still unable to find what's the problem, and it starts to drive me nuts. I'm guessing there's a punctuation mark missing somewhere.

In comparison, the model "triangloid" is properly working.

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INTRODUCTION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide}%  permet de dessiner des figures, des graphiques
%%  FONT
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgadventor}% paquet de police de caractère TGadventor
\usepackage{sansmath}%  Copie-colle la police active dans 
%                       \sfdefault (/!\ N'EST PAS UNE POLICE DE CARACTÈRES)
\usepackage{xcolor}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INPUT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\input{preamble.tex}
%\input{parameters.tex}

%\input{types/f2d_fig}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SETUP %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{fig2D/.style={font={\sansmath\sffamily\Large}, line width=0.4mm, line cap=round, line join=round, >=latex, x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm,}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SQUAROID %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{pics/squaroid/.style={%
    code={%
        \tikzset{squaroid/.cd,#1}%
        \def\pv##1{%
            \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/squaroid/##1}
            }
    \draw [solid, pic actions]
    % point o - bas gauche
    (0,0) coordinate (o) 
    node [inner sep=6pt, label={[\pv{poso}, inner sep=\pv{inner sep},]\pv{labo}}] {}
    % point a - bas droite
    (\pv{scale}*\pv{width},0) coordinate (a) 
    node [inner sep=6pt, label={[\pv{posa}, inner sep=\pv{inner sep},]\pv{laba}}] {}
    % point b - haut droite
    (\pv{scale}*\pv{width},\pv{scale}*\pv{height}) coordinate (b) 
    node [inner sep=6pt, label={[\pv{posb}, inner sep=\pv{inner sep},]\pv{labb}}] {}
    % point c - haut gauche
    (0,\pv{scale}*\pv{height}) coordinate (c) 
    node [inner sep=6pt, label={[\pv{posc}, inner sep=\pv{inner sep},]\pv{labc}}] {}
    % connexion entre les points
    (o) 
    -- (a) node [midway, label={[\pv{posA}, inner sep = \pv{inner sep},]\pv{labA}}] {}
    -- (b) node [midway, label={[\pv{posB}, inner sep = \pv{inner sep},]\pv{labB}}] {}
    -- (c) node [midway, label={[\pv{posC}, inner sep = \pv{inner sep},]\pv{labC}}] {}
    -- (o) node [midway, label={[\pv{posD}, inner sep = \pv{inner sep},]\pv{labD}}] {}
    ;
    }},
    squaroid/.cd,
    width/.initial=3,
    height/.initial=2,
    scale/.initial=1,
    labA/.initial=,
    labB/.initial=,
    labC/.initial=,
    labD/.initial=,
    labo/.initial=,
    laba/.initial=,
    labb/.initial=,
    labc/.initial=,
    posA/.initial=below,
    posB/.initial=right,
    posC/.initial=above,
    posD/.initial=left,
    poso/.initial=below,
    posa/.initial=below,
    posb/.initial=above,
    posc/.initial=above,
    inner sep/.initial=6pt,
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TRIANGLOID %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tikzset{pics/triangloid/.style={code={%
    \tikzset{triangloid/.cd,#1}%
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/triangloid/##1}}
    \draw [solid, pic actions, fill=\pv{fill}]
    %%  point o - bas gauche
    (0,0) coordinate (o) 
    node [inner sep=6pt, label={[\pv{poso}, inner sep=\pv{inner sep},]\pv{labo}}] {}
    %% point a - bas droite
    (\pv{scale}*\pv{width},0) coordinate (a)
    node [inner sep=6pt, label={[\pv{posa}, inner sep=\pv{inner sep},]\pv{laba}}] {}
    %% point b - sommet
    ({\pv{scale}*\pv{offset})},\pv{scale}*\pv{height}) coordinate (b)
    node [inner sep=6pt, label={[\pv{posb}, inner sep=\pv{inner sep},]\pv{labb}}] {}
    %% jonction entre les points
     (o) 
     -- (a) node [midway, label={[\pv{posA}, inner sep=\pv{inner sep},shift={(0pt,-6pt)}]\pv{labA}}] {}
     -- (b) node [midway, label={[\pv{posB}, inner sep=\pv{inner sep},]\pv{labB}}] {}
     -- (o) node [midway, label={[\pv{posC}, inner sep=\pv{inner sep},shift={(-2pt,0pt)}]\pv{labC}}] {}
     ;
  }},
  triangloid/.cd,
  width/.initial=5,
  height/.initial=2,
  offset/.initial=0,
  labA/.initial=,
  labB/.initial=,
  labC/.initial=,
  labo/.initial=,
  laba/.initial=,
  labb/.initial=,
  posA/.initial=below,
  posB/.initial=above right,
  posC/.initial=left,
  poso/.initial=below,
  posa/.initial=below,
  posb/.initial=above,
  inner sep/.initial=0pt,
  fill/.initial=black!0,
  scale/.initial=1,
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fig2D, rotate=0, scale=1.5]
        %%%     rectangle
        \begin{scope}
            \pic{squaroid={width=4, height=3, labo=N, laba=M, labb=P, labc=X, labC=4 cm, labD=3 cm, posD=right, scale=1.5}};
            \draw[]
                (o) -- (b) 
            ;
        \end{scope}
        %%%     Triangle
        \pic[rotate=90] {triangloid={width=3, height=1, offset=3, labb=O, posb=above, labC=$\sqrt{10}$ cm, scale=1.5}};
        \pic[rotate=-90] at (4,3) {triangloid={width=3, height=2.517, labb=Z, posb=above, scale=1.5}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look carefully at the error message, you'll see it says

```
I do not know the key '/tikz/below '
```

indicating that it's looking for a key called `below<space>`. In other words, you have a spurious space somewhere. In this case, it's caused  by a newline in the definition of `\pv`:

```
\def\pv##1{%
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/squaroid/##1}
    }
```

The newline before the closing brace adds a space, so change this definition to

```
\def\pv##1{%
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/squaroid/##1}% <-- add % here
    }
```

or

```
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/squaroid/##1}}
```

Comment: (Fair enough, that space wasn't really obvious in Overleaf's error view, but if you open the `.log` file I'm sure it'll be there.)

Comment: I think it was `\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/squaroid/##1}`. The errors disappears after adding the `%`. thank you!